# PowerShell: Reporting incorrect file length

Tags: powershell

The following script looks at files in two locations that should be duplicates of each other. I have written a portion of the script to examine whether the file sizes (.length) match. However, while one file reports the correct size, the other does not. Can you illustrate why this is and how I can correctly measure file size.

---

### Script

```
get-childitem -file -recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $comparisonFile=($_.FullName -replace 'Q:\\Backup Comparison\\E','V:\Q Dup Check Needed\E')
    $comparisonFileSize=$comparisonFile.Length
    Write-Host $_.FullName
    Write-Host $comparisonFile
    test-path $comparisonFile
    Write-Host $_.Length
    Write-Host $comparisonFileSize
    Write-Host ""
    sleep .1
}
```

---

### Output

```
Q:\Backup Comparison\E\EXCLUDE - FOUND\F(OUND) 01\found.000\dir0000.chk\._Vine_Street_ReportFinancialDetail_11_Q4.pdf
V:\Q Dup Check Needed\E\EXCLUDE - FOUND\F(OUND) 01\found.000\dir0000.chk\._Vine_Street_ReportFinancialDetail_11_Q4.pdf
True
4096
118
```

---

### Windows Reported File Size

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$comparisonFile` only contains the other file's path, and not the actual file object. Try this instead:

```
$comparisonFile = Get-Item ($_.FullName -replace 'Q:\\Backup Comparison\\E','V:\Q Dup Check Needed\E')
$comparisonFile.length
```

---

Depending on how accurate you need to be, I would recommend comparing file hashes rather than just the length, e.g. `Get-FileHash $comparisonFile -Algorithm "SHA256"`. Here's a more complete example: [Compare Filehash in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002072/7411885)